# How do I render search block programmatically?

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I'd like to render the search block in a twig file.

Comment: Why after you trying to render the search block inside a twig template and not in a region?

Comment: @Eyal Because the block will be hidden by default. And it will be displayed later in a popup, when clicking on a button. F.x., `<div style="display: none;">{{ block_search_form }}</div>`

Answer (score 4):

#### There is a big gotcha with the search form.

[The answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/203284/27710) with the `themename_search` only works if the search block is enabled or disabled and **has never been removed** in */admin/structure/block*.

If in */admin/structure/block* you re-add/place it again, the search form ID changes to `formsearch`. It no longer uses the theme name! And again it only works if this block is enabled or disabled, but not when removed.

---

A solution that works when search block has been removed from */admin/structure/block* is to use **[Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)** and then you can place it with

```
{{ drupal_form('Drupal\\search\\Form\\SearchBlockForm') }}
```

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat, this is a good workaround. I will keep looking for a solution that can print search form without a plugin.

Comment: I found a solution. It can be done by using the "[Including Part of Template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/including-part-template)". I use `{% include '@MYTHEME/block--search-form-block.html.twig' %}` on page.html.twig to include my customize `block--search-form-block.html.twig` search form.

Comment: I'm wrong. My solution does print the `block--search-form-block.html.twig` but the search form inside is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

please try this

```
/**
 * Implements theme_preprocess_example_hook().
 */
function themename_preprocess_example_hook(&$variables) {

  // Create a variable for the block w/ ID "example_block_id".
  $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('example_block_id');
  $variables['example_block'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getViewBuilder('block')
  ->view($block);

}
```

in your twig file

```
{{ example_block }}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page().
 *
 */
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    $block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('mytheme_search'); // replace mytheme part with your theme name.
    $variables['block_search_form'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
        ->getViewBuilder('block')
        ->view($block);
}
```

Access it in page.html.twig file

```
{{ block_search_form }}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work

Comment: @CocoSkin replace `mytheme_search` with the name of your theme. Ex: for Bartik theme it would be `bartik_search`.

Comment: @NoSssweat It does not work

Comment: @CocoSkin it does, you're doing something wrong. Did you also replace `mytheme` in the function name? Did you add this code to your theme's **.theme** file?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, my theme name is "testtheme". I use "`testtheme_search`" as ID on **testtheme.theme** file. The hook function is  `function testtheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) { }`.

Comment: And added `{{ block_search_form }}` to your testtheme page.html.twig? Flushed the cache?

Comment: If atill nothing, for testing purposes only, do the same with core's Bartik theme.

Comment: @NoSssweat I just tested on the Bartik theme and got the same error. I'm running Drupal 9.0.3 on Acquia Dev Desktop with PHP 7.3.15.

Comment: @CocoSkin Add `$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'verbose';` to settings.php to see the real error message.

Comment: [Here is a working D9 Bartik theme](https://github.com/no-sssweat/bartik) that will add an [extra search box](https://i.imgur.com/fteiiuI.png)

Comment: @NoSssweat I got the same error with that theme. Here is the screenshot on [error report](https://ibb.co/n33vVrx)

Comment: @CocoSkin mystery solved, see [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/296421/27710)