# How do I render search block form in theme template?

Tags: theming, search, 9

I've customized the search block in "block--search-form-block.html.twig" and it works using block layout on Drupal 9. Is it possible to render the Search Block directly in **page.html.twig**?

I've tried [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203267/how-do-i-render-search-block-programmatically) and it giving me error (The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.).

Comment: What ID did you use in the load function?

Comment: I've tried the "MYTHEME_search", "search_form_block", "search_block_form", "block_search_form", and "block_searchform".

Comment: See my comment in [How do I render search block programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203267/how-do-i-render-search-block-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the 3 methods I found.

**1 - Use `plugin.manger.block` to render `search_form_block`**

-- in `mytheme.theme`

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $customblock = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block')->createInstance('search_form_block', []);
  $variables['content']['custom_block_output'] = $customblock->build();
}
```

-- in `page.html.twig`

```
{{ content.custom_block_output }}
```

**2 - Same as 1 but render a customized search block from `block--search-form-block.html.twig`.**

-- in `mytheme.theme` - Same as method 1

-- in `page.html.twig`

```
{% include '@MYTHEME/block--search-form-block.html.twig' %}
```

**3 - Use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) - credit to [No Sssweat's Post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203267/how-do-i-render-search-block-programmatically/#answer-296421)**

1. install the Twig Tweak module
2. insert `{{ drupal_block(search_form_block') }}` on `page.html.twig`